# How do you create an empty file from the command line in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line

What is the best way to create an empty file from the command line in windows?

I have been using the [touch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_%28Unix%29) command but it isn't in stock windows.

One idea was to use `echo . >file` that works, but the file is never really empty that way. Is there a way to generate an empty file similar to what `touch file` would do using only what comes with stock windows.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210201/how-to-create-empty-text-file-from-a-batch-file/295214#295214)

```
type nul >file
```

Answer (score 6):

```
echo. 2> file
```

Give that one a try

Comment: +1 Don't know who marked this down as it *does* work

Comment: +1: Because I learned something, and this is a cool hack. :)

Comment: You can use any command, so if you wanted to make it even shorter how about: `cd 2> file` :)

Comment: @Gareth, think you meant echo 2> file although using the period after echo (echo.) will turn echo off to stop any other echo related messages showing

Comment: No, I was pointing out that this doesn't depend on echo at all, you can use any command (in this case I chose 'cd' because it's so short in length) so long as it doesn't output to the standard error stream (i.e. 2>). You'll basically be writing nothing to 'file'.

Comment: `You can use any command,` @8088, not *any* command, only commands which do not output anything to `stderr`. For example, try `ren 2> file`.

Answer (score 3):

```
copy con file [Enter]
[F6] (or [Ctrl-Z]) [Enter]
```

:)

Comment: copy nul file ....