# how to create a text file using the windows commandline

Tags: windows, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you create an empty file from the command line in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/272972/how-do-you-create-an-empty-file-from-the-command-line-in-windows)

Is there any command, using that we can create a text file or any other format. To make a folder we use md command, but to creat a file.

Comment: I assume you are talking about the windows command line?

Comment: yes. You are right.

Comment: You should specify a version of Windows you are on.  For XP there used to be `edit`, but that isn't enabled by default in 7 (not sure if you can enable either).  Personally, I would suggest downloading [vim](http://www.vim.org/download.php) for Windows and adding it to your PATH.  It's very powerful, well supported, and has good documentation.  Then you could do `vim C:\Users\file.txt` to make (or edit) the file that's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type nul >> name.ext` will create an empty name.ext file .

Comment: Yes. It is working perfectly. One more thing can you tell me from where I will get this type of commands documentation. Because these are not available in commandline help

Comment: Here's the list: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772390%28v=ws.10%29.aspx